# Attached event to selector which is added by another event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If the title is not description enough, the problem:

I have an element on a page, a button, that injects HTML into another element once clicked. Within the HTML that gets added, is a `div.text_original="Create New Project"` with an anchor that needs to fire a light box (looking at FancyBox), however, I cannot seem to attach a custom event to this anchor.

I cannot modify the JavaScript that fires the initial HTML addition, and the `.on()` function in jQuery is not working for me.

The code I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
   $('div[text_original="Create New Project"]').on('click', function() {
       alert('click');
   });

});
```

The selector, `div[text_original="Create New Project"]` is only 'accessible' once the user clicks on a button to populate an empty div (on first load) with a collection of menu items, each item is wrapped by a div and contains an attribute called text_original with a unique value, thus the reason I'm using it as my selector.

How can I attach, without modifying the JS that builds this collection of div elements, after the user clicks on the button?

Like stated, the `.on()` does not work in this scenario.

**Update**

I understand the premise behind this, however, I'm still unable to get this working.

The structure before the button is clicked:

```
span[button]
   span
```

User clicks on `span[button]` and the DOM looks like this:

```
span[button]
   span
   div[new element]
      div
         ul
          li
           div
             a[what i need to bind to]
```

Should my selector contain the full traverse here? Because just binding to `div[] a` still does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event delegation model of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has a different syntax, the event should be registered to a static element and the selector for the dynamic element has to be passed as the second parameter

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $(document).on('click', 'div[text_original="Create New Project"]', function() {
       alert('click');
   });
});
```

the syntax you have used is same as

```
$('div[text_original="Create New Project"]').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the `on()` properly in this case.. **you need to delegate it to closest static parent**..

try this

```
 $(document).on('click','div[text_original="Create New Project"]',function() {
   alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach an event to an element that does not yet exist when the ready event is fired off.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   $('#existingelement').on( 'click', 'div[text_original="Create New Project"]'), function() {
       alert('click');
   });

});
```

Attaching it to a specific ancestor of your dynamically created element is slightly better than attaching it to the document. This is because jQuery has to check for all events that bubble up to the document whether to fire off your event handler.

More info on the jquery page [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[text_original="Create New Project"]', function() {
   alert('click');
});
```

Note that `document` in my example should be changed to the nearest element to the div in the page which is available on load - most usually this is the element which is being appended to.